# Is utf_8_spanish_ci collation in MariaDB 10.2 working correctly?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation

The code is from the MySQLCookbook, 3rd edition

```
CREATE TABLE t (c CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET utf8);
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES('cg'),('ch'),('ci'),('lk'),('ll'),('lm');
SELECT c FROM t ORDER BY c COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

results in cg, ch, ci, lk, ll, lm

```
SELECT c FROM t ORDER BY c COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci;
```

In the book, results are cg, ci, ch, lk, lm, ll
but when I run the query under MariaDB 10.2,
the results are unchanged from the "general" collation:
cg, ch, ci, lk, ll, lm

According to the book, "ch" and "cl" are treated as single characters in Spanish ordering.
Is the result of the second query evidence of a bug in MariaDB?

Comment: Since your test case works "correctly" for me in 5.6.22, I suggest you file a bug with MariaDB.